# Errno 14 PYCURL ERROR 22

Tags: yum

I am getting an error when updating yum. I have "yum clean all" and still getting the error. I have check my plesk-php5.3.repo and the address is correct and when i go directly to the file it is there. However when i go to the web directory there is no file  with that name.

plesk-php-5.3                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
http://autoinstall.plesk.com/PHP_5.3/dist-rpm-CentOS-6-x86_64/repodata/64f5125242ecc9b0fef7dadaf7a2119b0c117abdc3f590227890c0fce7969b0d-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.